# .Net Webapi doesen't show errormessage of required properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, error-handling, data-annotations, modelstate

I've got a **.Net WebAPI-project** which receives data-objects form multiple clients and processes them.

I want to make sure, that the JSON-messages do contain all required fields.

To ensure this, I added a `Required` attribute (`System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`) to all properties which have to be set by the client.

This is working fine when i check `ModelState.IsValid`, but now i want to throw a helpful `BadRequest` which should contain the `ErrorMessage` set in the `Required` attribute.

#### Model

```
public class DataModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "ExampleProperty is required!")]
    public string ExampleProperty { get; set; }
}
```

#### Controller

```
public class DataController
{
    public DataModel PostData(DataModel data)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // This part is working fine..
            return ProcessData(data);
        }
        else
        {
            // errs do only contain Exception.Messages not ErrorMessages..
            string errs = string.Join(
                    "\n",
                    ModelState.Values
                        .SelectMany(s => s.Errors)
                        .Select(e => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.ErrorMessage) ? (e.Exception != null ? e.Exception.Message : null) : e.ErrorMessage)
                        .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
                        .GroupBy(g => g).Select(s => s.Key + " (#" + s.Count() + ")"));

            throw new Exception("...todo: fill in correct text...");
        }
    }
}
```

#### ModelState.Values.First().Errors

- Exception contains: "Required property 'ExampleProperty' not found in JSON. Path [...]"
- But the ErrorMessage is empty.

Any ideas what could cause this? What did i do wrong?

Comment: I tried it an got the same XML output, but `errs` contains the expected error message, no idea why it fails on your side. Maybe try again. Regarding the XML output try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112892/serialize-modelstatedictionary-to-xml

Comment: @jps Thanks! The Xml-Serialization was wrong. I did a setup to debug the webapi and looked manually into the `errors`. The exception is set correctly, but the ErrorMessage doesn't contain the text, which I set in the attribute...

Answer (score 0):

Try to using this :

```
public IHttpActionResult PostData(DataModel data)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // This part is working fine..
            return Ok(ProcessData(data));
        }
        else
        {
            // errs do only contain Exception.Messages not ErrorMessages..
            string errs = ModelState.Select(x => x.Value.Errors)
                       .Where(y=>y.Count>0)
                       .ToList();
            return Ok(errs);
        }
    }
```

which will return a response with your model if the requested model `data` is valid
and if the model is not valid will return `list of string` with the error messages